# How to parse index.php in server root by default in HipHop / HHVM (and fix the "404 File Not Found" error)?

Tags: php, hiphop, hhvm

#### Reproduceable problem description:

When installing HipHop / HHVM via the official way [[1](https://github.com/facebook/hhvm/wiki/Prebuilt-Packages-on-Ubuntu-12.04)][[2](https://github.com/facebook/hhvm#installing)], and then running the built-in server [[3](https://github.com/facebook/hhvm#running)] from /var/www via

```
cd /var/www
sudo hhvm -m server
```

it will render a custom "404 File Not Found" message to the browser, regardless of /var/www's contents when moving to the server's root:

```
http://111.111.111.111/
```

However, HipHop will run perfectly when a filename is given, like

```
http://111.111.111.111/index.php
```

Filling the index.php with phpinfo() will also show "hiphop" as feedback, indicating that this PHP file is correctly parsed by HipHop.

#### Question:

How to let HipHop's server run index.php (etc.) by default when navigating to the server's root, like Nginx and Apache do ?

#### Update:

Seems to be a common issue: [[4](https://github.com/facebook/hhvm/issues/1301)], [[5](https://github.com/facebook/hhvm/issues/749)]

Comment: So this question isn't really about 404s, but about setting up your default index page. Can you fix the title please?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I totally agree, but the 404 error message in the title might lead people with the same problem to this Q/A via Google. What do you think, is this a valid reason for keeping the title ?

Comment: I think it's too general. A question about 404s could be almost anything, but in this case you are asking how to configure something very specific.

Answer (score 2):

According to [the documentation](https://github.com/facebook/hhvm/wiki/Runtime-options#server), the `config.hdf` file has a `DefaultDocument` directive. Set that.

Comment: The `DefaultDocument = index.php` is set in `server.hdf` (needs to be in there, not in config.hdf afaik) by default (and in my setup too), the problem still exists.

Comment: @Panique: Can you show any evidence for this `server.hdf` theory of yours? I've not looking into it too deeply but I saw no hint of that in the documentation I linked you to.

Answer (score 1):

For HHVM 3.0 you specify it in a `ini` config file with this:

```
  hhvm.server.default_document = index.php
```